# Representing units for concentration of a liquid (v/v)%

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm doing an experiment which involves testing a particular solution in different concentrations. Since this is a liquid, the concentration should be represented in v/v % rather than w/v %. However, I'm not sure how to represent this in my research question. Suppose, these are the concentrations I'm testing: 20, 40, 60, 80.

Should I express it like (20%, 40%, 60%, 80% (v/v))
(or)
(20,40,60,80 (v/v)%)
(or)
20%(v/v), 40%(v/v), 60%(v/v), 80%(v/v)

Comment: Anything is fine as long you explicitly state what it is. You can even write one line in the experimental stating that all percentages are reported as volume/volume. Repeating v/v looks odd in the last choice.

Comment: The point is that v/v is one of the less clear way to express concentration as for everything is fine as far as you prepare the solutions but suddenly becomes a mess if one is seeking relation to other properties. Volumes aren't additive. I have no idea if parts per volume is a recommended way, but] at least it has a preparative connotation. Note that one can still use w/v. That would give unequivocally the amount of one component in a volume of the *final* solutions. Con is that one might need density of them, afterwards. It is all matter of protocols, glassware available, and purposes.

Comment: Nonconforming units such as "v/v %" and "w/v %" should not be used at all.

Comment: The use of v/v % depends on the field. For HPLC, all instruments are designed to use v/v % and this is a billion dollar industry. From a physical chemist's point of view, this is a bad practice.